# Store the video from Documents directory to Photos album

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video, ios-camera

I have stored the video in Documents directory for temporary.

Here's the sample video path : file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C651A13F-8F7C-4FCB-A1D9-D6D4C5F512E7/Documents/mergeVideo.mov

I would like to save this video in Album directory .. For this i have to convert this file url to asset url.

I have tried the ways to resolve.. But doesn't help to resolve .. Can anyone please guide ..?

To make work this code i have to convert the file url to asset url .. How to do this ?

I already have the code to save the video using asset url .. Here's my code :

```
-(void)save2cameraRoll{


NSString *albumName=@"album name";
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:albumName
                         resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group) {
                             NSLog(@"added album:%@", albumName);
                         }
                        failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                            NSLog(@"error adding album");

                        }];

__block ALAssetsGroup* groupToAddTo;
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum
                       usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
                           if ([[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] isEqualToString:albumName]) {
                               NSLog(@"found album %@", albumName);
                               groupToAddTo = group;
                           }
                       }
                     failureBlock:^(NSError* error) {
                         NSLog(@"failed to enumerate albums:\nError: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                     }];

NSURL *fileURL = videoInputUrl;


[library assetForURL:fileURL
         resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
             // assign the photo to the album
             [groupToAddTo addAsset:asset];
             NSLog(@"Added %@ to %@", [[asset defaultRepresentation] filename], albumName);
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Video Saved to HubRamped Album."  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil, nil];
             [alert show];
         }
        failureBlock:^(NSError* error) {
            NSLog(@"failed to retrieve image asset:\nError: %@ ", [error localizedDescription]);
        }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code snippet to save the video and add that video in custom album ..

```
 [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoInputUrl completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
    if (error) {

        NSLog(@"Final Video could not be saved");
    }
    else{

            [library assetForURL:assetURL
                     resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                         // assign the photo to the album
                         [groupToAddTo addAsset:asset];
                         NSLog(@"Added %@ to %@", [[asset defaultRepresentation] filename], albumName);
                         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Video Saved to HubRamped Album."  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil, nil];
                         [alert show];
                     }
                    failureBlock:^(NSError* error) {
                        NSLog(@"failed to retrieve image asset:\nError: %@ ", [error localizedDescription]);
                    }];
    }
}];
```